# Naming code and project files .NET

Tags: .net, naming-conventions

What is general convention followed in code files and project files naming ?

Also how are the namespaces named ?

My dilemma is: I have say a client-server architecture.

I organised as client and server folders then, prefix project names with Client or Server.

eg. ServerDataAccess.csproj

Within that if i have data access for classes Class1, Class2 , do i name them Class1DataAccess... and what about the codefile name ?

because 'Class1' as a class is in another project. So it gives clear idea from filename and class name abt its objective.

But repeating DataAccess everytime also seems bad, since the parent project already suggests dataaccess.

Comment: See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx and this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.

Comment: My ususal practise is to name it according to the namespace it has in it, if they are same for more classes then name it according to their function.. @Adrian Faciu good link there........